# How to place 2 divs 1 in the middle and 1 on the right side

Tags: html, css

I would like to place my 2 divs(1 in the middle and 1 on the right side). Here's my codes. I am not sure if its right or wrong sorry. I would like to have the same output as the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXqpW.png

here's my code

```html
 <div class="payment " style="background-color: #370a0c;padding: 1px 0;background-image: url(image/rectangle2.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: right;background-size: 230px 79px; ">
                <div id="payment_row" class="row " style="width: 100%; text-align:center; padding-top: 20px; ">
                    <div class="col-9 ">
                        <ul class="payment-list" style="display: flex; margin: auto; ">
                            <li style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "><img src="image/visa.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/Mastercard.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/amex.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/paypal.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="payment-list-2" style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/discover.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="payment-list-3" style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/Maestro.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="payment-list-3" style="padding-right: 20px; ">
                                <a href=" "></a><img src="image/skrill.png " alt=" "></img>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="payment" class="col-2 " style="display:flex; ">
                        <ul style="display: flex; margin-right: 3px; margin-left: -70px;">
                            <a href=" "></a><img id="player_img" src="image/icon-people.png " alt=" " style="width: 47px;height: 47px;margin-top: -8px;"></img>
                        </ul>
                        <ul style="margin-left: -28px;">
                            <li>
                                <h1 id="player_num" style="font-size: 35px; line-height: 15px; margin-right: 45px; ">
                                    21,765
                                </h1>
                            </li>
                            <li id="player_count" style="line-height: 15px; margin-right: 15px; margin-left: -30px;margin-top: 11px;">
                                Online Players
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

help me please thank you!

Comment: Provide example with an online code editor like https://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a container with 2 children and add `margin-left: auto;` to both of the child and they will align as you wanted.

**Below is just a POC**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: darkred;
  color: white;
}

.flex-container>* {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
}

.list>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.list>ul>li+li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>count:213213</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using some sort of framework like Bootstrap (with `col-`), which handles the responsiveness for you. In this case you should consider the container 'width' to be made up of 12 'units'. A combination of `col-3` + `col-6` + `col-3` would equal `12`, with more 'space' occupied by the central element.

Outside of frameworks, you're on the right track with attempting to use flexbox. Though note that you shouldn't be applying `margin` to flexbox (and you should never use inline styles).

Here's a **very** stripped down example of how to configure this using flexbox. All you need is `display: flex` on the container, and `flex: 1` on the three elements you want to align next to one another. Note that you can even use an empty element if you don't want three, as can be seen below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container ul {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <ul>
    <!-- Empty Left Column -->
  </ul>
  <ul>
    Payment List
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1 id="player_num">
        21,765
      </h1>
    </li>
    <li id="player_count">
      Online Players
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```